# Disabling mousewheel until function ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a page scroller. It works like this:

- you're on the `page 1` slide, you scroll your mouse down
- you're being (using `animate`) scrolled down to `page 2`
- and it goes like this for up/down scrolling :))

My problem is - when I scroll multiple times during the animation, it stutters. How can I prevent that?

My slide code is here:

```
function scrollPages() {
        $('section.main').each(function() {
            var prevSection = $(this).prev('section.main'),
                nextSection = $(this).next('section.main'),
                id = $(this).attr('id'),
                scrollFunc = function(dest) {
                $('body, html').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: dest
                }, 'slow');
            }

            function goUp() {
                if(prevSection.attr('id') != undefined) {
                    var scrollTo = prevSection.offset().top;

                    if(prevSection.attr('id') == 'hi') {
                        $('div.animation').children('div.first').stop().animate({ top: '0' },823);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.secound').stop().animate({ left: '0' },933);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.third').stop().animate({ top: '146px' },559);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.fourth').stop().animate({ top: '30px' },1085);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.fifth').stop().animate({ left: '60px' },860);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.sixth').stop().animate({ top: '30px' },798);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.seventh').stop().animate({ left: '0' },869);
                    }
                    scrollFunc(scrollTo)
                }
            }

            function goDown() {
                if(nextSection.attr('id') != undefined) {
                    var scrollTo = nextSection.offset().top;
                    if(id == 'hi') {
                        $('div.animation').children('div.first').stop().animate({ top: '-999px' },423);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.secound').stop().animate({ left: '-1509px' },533);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.third').stop().animate({ top: '-999px' },359);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.fourth').stop().animate({ top: '-999px' },785);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.fifth').stop().animate({ left: '1999px' },560);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.sixth').stop().animate({ top: '-999px' },498);
                        $('div.animation').children('div.seventh').stop().animate({ left: '-9999px' },569);
                    }

                    scrollFunc(scrollTo);
                }
            }

            $(this).on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
                if(delta > 0) {
                    goUp();
                } else {
                    goDown();
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

Comment: Maybe using something like `_.throttle()`: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Comment: It would require using whole `underscore.js`, woudn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Poke at the source to see if you can just copy-paste that one function? (To my eyes that seems possible, it doesn't really have any dependencies.) Or google for "javascript throttle" to find a code snippet version.

Comment: I tried using `debounce`, it's something similar, but it stopped scrolling only after a couple of pixels :(

Comment: Odd. If I understand your code correctly, what you want to do is scroll by one page anytime the user clicks on their scrollwheel, right? That is, override scrolling line-by-line. `throttle()` seems more appropriate here. The two functions work the other way around. `throttle()` invokes the event handler immediately then ignores further events for a time. `debounce()` ignores event handlers for a time, then invokes the handler for the last one that comes in.

Comment: Also: shouldn't you call `event.preventDefault()` in the `mousewheel` handler?

Comment: I created another question regarding usage of `debounce/throttle` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896565/how-to-use-jquerys-debounce